# Mobile App to Auto Fill and Submit a web form, from a source of data

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, mobile-application

I have a mobile app project, that need to auto fill a web form from a source of data (excel/txt/json/etc), and post it automatically. I see the tutorial on youtube, somebody doing it via windows app (using Visual Basic), here's the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKB0K3F1enU

I want to do something similar like that, but it will be a mobile app. 
So the plan is, the app will have 1 button, when user press it, it will fill the specific web form from a source of data (excel/txt/json/etc), and then submit the data automatically.
The target devices will be iOS, android, windows phone, so a multi platform framework/sdk will be perfect.

I did several research but I cant't find any solution.

Do anybody have any idea, which framework I should use? or what is the best way to do it for mobile app?

I really appreciate any help and solution, thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: Have you found something since then?

Answer (score 0):

It's not simple, I would do it by doing the parsing of the JSON file and, according to the elements, creating dinamically and programmatically a form and filling it.

For istance if you get from the parsing 3 texts and the first node is called "email", the second "password" and the third "confirm password", you'll create from a Java class these elements:
a textView with this text: "email"
an EditText with the name "Edit" + "email" and text with the specific content found;
a textView with this text: "password"
an EditText with the name "Edit" + "password" and text with the specific content found;
a textView with this text: "confirm password"
an EditText with the name "Edit" + "confirmpassword" and text with the specific content found;
A submit button.